# Is calling functions and creating new variables in react component body bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working with react for years and I still have a simple question that I could never understand nor get the answer anywhere. Is calling an outside function in react component body bad?

For example:

```
import { getUser } from './helpers';

function MyComponent() {
  const user = getUser();

  return (
    ...
```

What will happen to user variable when component gets re-rendered by the parent component? Variables created in component body are created again in memory? Should I use `useCallback` or `useMemo`? I feel those two react functions are for other reasons, as expensive calculations and to prevent unecessary prop re-render.

Comment: It really depends on what the function does. Is it fetching the user on some external service? Then definitely not inside of render unless it's properly wrapped in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and kept inside some state. And even then, is the component re-used all over the app? Fetching each time the component is used seems inefficient, maybe a [context provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) is the right place! Your question can't really be answered as-is.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yeah, I'm aware of that, let's say that getUser just returns an object.

Comment: It then depends on if that object is a stable reference or a new object each time, which would trigger re-renders if then passed down to other components as props, or would trigger effects more than expected if used as a dependency. It really depends on the use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question in my experience I've never heard of calling outside functions within a react body as bad. In fact it's always been something that was encouraged especially for helper functions like in your example. There are definitely other ways to handle helper functions that may be needed multiple times (useContext comes to mind) but I don't see anything wrong with importing an outside function to call within a react body.

As far as what happens to `user` in your example it would get reset to the new return of `getUser()` upon any component re-render.

Answer (score 0):

The `user` variable will be set to the value returned by getUser() on each re-render. And yet, getUser() will run on each re-render.

React Hooks are functions with `use` at the beginning of the function name, [documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).